# What can the "options" setting be used for in Symfony2 routing definitions/configuration?

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm seeing some places where there is an "options" property on routes (below is taken from https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#generating-uris):

```
my_route_to_expose:
    pattern: /foo/{id}/bar
    defaults: { _controller: HelloBundle:Hello:index }
    options:
        expose: true
```

Note the "options" key under "my_route_to_expose".

While this obviously exists, I cannot see any place in the Symfony documentation that mentions this.  I've also tried poking around the code in the project that the above example came from, but cannot seem to find where they are picking up on this at all.

From what I can assume (since I see no documentation for it) is that it can be used to store just arbitrary data with a route that you as the developer can pick up on and use, however, I don't know when and where you would be using this information at.

So, what can this be used for and in what context can it be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

That key is used by `FOSJsRoutingBundle` and is not a part of `Symfony2` core.

By default `FOSJsRoutingBundle` doesn't expose all your route (I think for performance & security reasons) but only those that have that key set to true.

Comment: I guess what I was getting at is how I could utilize the "options" feature in my own bundle, just like the FOSJsRoutingBundle does.